# Inequality for series with constraint

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have difficulty with the following estimation.
Let $x_n$, $n=1,2,3,\dots$ satisfy
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x^2_n + \left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n\right)^2 = M < +\infty.$$
Let $a_n$, $n=1,2,3,\dots$ satisfy $1 > a_1 > a_2 > \dots > a_n> \dots >0$, $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to +\infty$. Can we find the maximum and minimum of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx_n$?
I intend to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but the sum includes infinitely many terms.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz works as well for infinite series. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Second_example:_sequence_spaces

Comment: If the $x_n$ sequence has no constraints, how to you get max or min?

Comment: @herbsteinberg it has a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

**Some thoughts**:

For convenience, let $M = 1$.

**Fact** 1: Given $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n\ge 0$, the maximum of $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i$ subject to $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2 \le 1$ is given by
$$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2 - \frac{1}{n + 1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i\right)^2}$$
when
$$x_j = \frac{b_j - \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^n b_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2 - \frac{1}{n + 1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i\right)^2}}, \quad j = 1, 2, \cdots, n.$$
(*Proof*: Use Lagrange Multipliers.)

**Fact 2**: Given a sequence $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ with $b_i \ge 0, \forall i\ge 1$, we have, for all $n \ge 1$,
$$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2 - \frac{1}{n + 1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i\right)^2}
\le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} b_i^2 - \frac{1}{n + 2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} b_i\right)^2}.$$
(*Proof*: We have
$\mathrm{RHS}^2 - \mathrm{LHS}^2
= \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i - b_{n+1} - n b_{n+1})^2 \ge 0$.)

**Discussion**:

Let
$$S = \left\{(x_1, x_2, \cdots)
: ~ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 + \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n\right)^2 = 1\right\}.$$

(1) If $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n + 1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2 = 0$, we have
$$\sup_{S}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x_n
= \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2}. \tag{1}$$
(The proof is given at the end.)

---

*proof of* (1):

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x_n
\le \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2}
\le \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2}.$$

On the other hand, for any $\epsilon > 0$,
there exists $N$ such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x_n = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N a_i^2 - \frac{1}{N + 1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N a_i\right)^2} > (1 - \epsilon)\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2}$$
when $x_{N + 1} = x_{N+2} = \cdots = 0$ etc. (See Fact 1).

We are done.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and your help. However, here we don't have the condition that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a^2_n < +\infty$.

Comment: @LarryBaynes If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 = \infty$, I have no idea.